# How can you set top and left position with javascript without it rounding the value

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, jquery-ui, responsive-design

I'm making an UI where the user drags and resizes things around; it has to be very responsive, so I convert the top and left on jQueryUI's drag or resize's stop event to percentages.

To simplify my question, when you set the position, let's say like this:

```
document.querySelector(".widget").style.top= "1.23456789%"
```

, this:

```
console.log(document.querySelector(".widget").style.top)
```

returns

```
"1.23457%"
```

(Rounds to five decimals)

As it has to be a very precise interface, I need .widget's top to be set as exactly 1.23456789% in that case.

Thanks in advance for your ideas on this!

Comment: This makes no sense; a screen is made up of discrete pixels. For a normal sized screen, the distinction between the two values is like a 10,000th of a pixel, which is not recognizable by human vision.

Comment: Yeah, but converting to % moves the widgets sometimes a little to the left and/or to the top

Comment: Keep track of positions in your own JavaScript variables. You can't do anything about what the browser does with the position values, but at least you can keep your own idea of precision.

Comment: So there's no way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You cannot make the web browser do what it doesn't feel like doing.